# c# -- Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun

Tags: c#, .net, memory

I have a long running i/o heavy (network/disk) multithreaded c# desktop application that sporadically crashes with "Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun."

A typical stack trace of the crashing thread is shown below.

The program runs for anywhere between 30 minutes and 6 hours before it typically crashes with a similar stack.

I have inspected the stack traces of the other application threads during a crash and haven't noticed any patterns.

I have considered that there may be a hardware issue, but there is much activity on the machine and no other signs of corruption (application crashes, event log errors, etc).

The C# application uses no `unsafe` blocks and no libraries that use `unsafe` blocks as far as I have determined.

Two questions:

- Is it possible to get symbols for the System.ni.dll calls in the trace below?
- How can I go about determining the cause of the crash?  (My strongest suspicion is a framework bug.)

My system is i5-4790k (not overclocked), Windows 2012R2, targeting .net 4.6 x64, fully patched.

Visual studio 2015, fully patched.

Running the `Debug` build.

```
clr.dll!__report_gsfailure()    Unknown
clr.dll!SafeHandle::Release(bool)   Unknown
clr.dll!SafeHandle::Dispose(void)   Unknown
clr.dll!SafeHandle::DisposeNative(class SafeHandle *)   Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765ddc4b()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765dda8a()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765e7e0e()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765c420f()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765c41d4()    Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!00007ffa7740f18a()  Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa76b19bbf()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765e0d0b()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa7657ac4f()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765e0508()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765e0319()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765e714d()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765e6cdd()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765e0157()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765dfe48()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765dfdb5()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765dfa0d()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765de83d()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765de401()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765de2e0()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765dacac()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765da9f0()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765da22e()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765d7fc7()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa765d743d()    Unknown
System.ni.dll!00007ffa76579af6()    Unknown
00007ffa19832eb7()  Unknown
00007ffa1978eb0f()  Unknown
00007ffa19844cfa()  Unknown
00007ffa199e83d7()  Unknown
00007ffa1978ce48()  Unknown
00007ffa1978ccb5()  Unknown
00007ffa199e810f()  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!00007ffa77d37116()  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!00007ffa77d22a90()  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!00007ffa77dfa795()  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!00007ffa773d2c97()  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!00007ffa773fa77e()  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!00007ffa773fa617()  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!00007ffa773d2f3d()  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!00007ffa773d2608()  Unknown
mscorlib.ni.dll!00007ffa77386b50()  Unknown
clr.dll!CallDescrWorkerInternal()   Unknown
clr.dll!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler(struct CallDescrData *,int)  Unknown
clr.dll!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker(unsigned __int64 const *)  Unknown
clr.dll!QueueUserWorkItemManagedCallback(void *)    Unknown
clr.dll!Frame::Push(void)   Unknown
clr.dll!Frame::Push(void)   Unknown
clr.dll!Frame::Push(void)   Unknown
clr.dll!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem(bool *,bool *) Unknown
clr.dll!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem(bool *,bool *) Unknown
clr.dll!ThreadpoolMgr::ExecuteWorkRequest(bool *,bool *)    Unknown
clr.dll!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart(void *)    Unknown
clr.dll!Thread::intermediateThreadProc(void *)  Unknown
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  Unknown
```

Comment: Is that the actual error message above?  I would be looking for anything recursive in your code

Comment: Does this app crash in visual studio?  If yes can you pinpoint the line of code by breaking on exception thrown .... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh(v=VS.100).aspx  Does it stop in the same place each time?

Comment: Hi Mick, the actual error message is " Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun".  It crashes in different spots.  Why do you think this is a recursion issue?  Yes, it crashed in MSVC.  The stack trace above is from MSVC during a crash.  Thanks.

Comment: Stack errors and recursion go hand in hand.  Although there's plenty of other possiblities.  I think you're going to need to post some code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Did you find any reason or workaround or strategy to mitigate this?
We now have the same problem with System.Net.HttpWebRequests. No recursion, just issuing requests that sometimes time out, sometimes are successful und sometimes give other errors.
The exception (tearing down the whole application) also occurs in clr.dll in SafeHandle::Release(bool).
Runing on .NET 4.7.1, Windows Server 2016.

Comment: @CSharper oh man, it's been a while.  i'm not sure exactly when this went away for me.  i did have a hardware issue.  try running on another machine if you can and see if it disappears?

Comment: From what I can see the issue happens within framework libraries. These may use unsafe blocks even if your app doesn't. If you can reproduce this failure, try running it under [windbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sos-dll-sos-debugging-extension). When/if the crash happens, you can use SOS to get a more informative stack trace (via `clrstack`).

Alternatively, you can open an issue on the [VS Community Portal](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html). If you have a crash dump handy you can attach it to your issue..

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar behavior. I suppose it is a bug in RyuJIT compiler. To avoid this you need to fallback to JIT64 using `<useLegacyJit enabled="1" />` in app.config. Like this:

```
<runtime>
  <useLegacyJit enabled="1" />
</runtime>
```